# how to disable selection for few rows based on any condition in multi selection of igx-grid ignite UI for angular?

Tags: angular, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I want to disable selection of some rows in multi-selection of igx-grid ignite UI for angular so that if I make those rows selected by default then the user should not be able to deselect those rows. 
I will appreciate any help to achieve the goal.

Comment: provide the sample code!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`onRowSelectionChange`](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html#onrowselectionchange) event emitter and inside your handler, check if the `newSelection` includes rows (by record id) that shouldn't be selected, if yes, remove them. If the `newSelection` excludes rows that should be selected, then include them.

```html
<igx-grid #grid (onRowSelectionChange)="adjustSelection($event)"
          [data]="localData"
          [autoGenerate]="true">
    ......
</igx-grid>
```